# What cause the error "Couldn't canonicalise: No such file or directory" in SFTP?

Tags: sftp

I am trying to use SFTP to upload the entire directory to remote host but I got a error.(I know SCP does work, but I really want to figure out the problem of SFTP.)

I used the command as below:
`(echo "put -r LargeFile/"; echo quit)|sftp -vb - username@remotehost:TEST/`

But I got the error "Couldn't canonicalise: No such file or directory""Unable to canonicalise path "/home/s1238262/TEST/LargeFile"

I thought it was caused by access rights. So, I opened a SFTP connection to the remote host in interactive mode and tried to create a new directory "LargeFile" in TEST/. And I succeeded. Then, I used the same command as above to uploading the entire directory "LargeFile". I also succeeded. The subdirectories in LargeFile were create or copied automatically.

So, I am confused. It seems only the LargeFile/ directory cannot be created in non-interactive mode. What's wrong with it or my command?

Answer (score 27):

With SFTP you can only copy if the directory exists. So

```
> mkdir LargeFile
> put -r path_to_large_file/LargeFile
```

Same as the advice in the link from @Vidhuran but this should save you some reading.

Comment: A more popular [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52022/339015). Hope someone will come across these answers and explain why this is the case.

Answer (score 5):

This error could possibly occur because of the `-r` option. Refer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/uploading-directories-with-sftp

Answer (score 2):

A better way is through using scp.

```
scp -r LargeFile/"; echo quit)|sftp -vb - username@remotehost:TEST/
```

Comment: Not if you want security.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me was to zip my folder on local `LargeFile.zip` and simply  `put LargeFile.zip`

```
zip -r LargeFile.zip LargeFile
sftp www.mywebserver.com (or ip of the webserver)
put LargeFile.zip (it will be on your remote server local directory)
unzip Largefile.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04, the sftp has a bug. If you have the '/' added to the file name, you will get the **Couldn't canonicalize: Failure** error.

For example:

> sftp> cd my_inbox/ ##will give you an error
>
> sftp> cd my_inbox  ##will NOT give you the error

Notice how the forward-slash is missing in the correct request.  The forward slash appears when you use the TAB key to auto-populate the names in the path.