# WSO2 P.PaaS installation failure : Invalid Partition Detected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wso2, paas

I have this list of error messages when I run the `boot.sh` command. At the end, I see this message.

```
**************************************************************
Management Console : https://something.private.paas:9443/console
**************************************************************

boot.sh: WSO2 Private PaaS installation completed successfully!
```

But, I am not even able to logon to console. How do I get around the error messages and get a successful installation?

Note, when running `boot.sh`, I get a prompt as `Enter EC2 credentials :` which I believe is the AWS secret key (because, the field to be typed into is a password field). However, the document [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-Step2:ConfiguringtheWSO2PrivatePaaSInstance) refers to entering *both* access key and secret keys. Could this be a reason?

```
Deploying partition at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/partition.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Invalid Partition Detected : P1. Cause: POST https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1 -> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"}}Deploying autoscale policy at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/autoscale-policy.json
{"stratosAdminResponse":{"message":"Successfully deployed autoscaling policy definition with id economy"}}Deploying deployment policy at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/deployment-policy.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Deployment policy is invalid: [id] deployp"}}Deploying deployment policy at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/deployment-flat.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Deployment policy is invalid: [id] deployf"}}Deploying LB cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/lb-cart.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying Aplication Server (AS) Manager cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/appserver-cart-mgt.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying Application Service Manager service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] appservermgt [alias] f579b9c2-7315-4c2b-ab04-9f6cc4c101a3 . Cause: appservermgt is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying Aplication Server (AS) Worker cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/appserver-cart-worker.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying Application Service Worker service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] appserverworker [alias] 42174455-c01f-4b2a-a9ae-d40694768697 . Cause: appserverworker is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying API Manager (AM) - Gateway cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/gateway.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying API Manager - Gateway service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] gateway [alias] f55ef728-405e-44de-8dac-6990fe65983c . Cause: gateway is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying API Manager (AM) - Gateway manager cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/gatewaymgt.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying API Manager - Gateway manager service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] gatewaymgt [alias] 08381456-b720-4280-8904-1a8fa294901b . Cause: gatewaymgt is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying API Manager (AM) - Keymanager cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/keymanager.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying API Manager (AM) - Keymanager service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] keymanager [alias] 93e67ddb-86f2-416b-8feb-b1a4e4bc6d82 . Cause: keymanager is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying API Manager (AM) - Publisher cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/publisher.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying API Manager (AM) - Publisher service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] publisher [alias] 95de5e64-7169-49d1-a4d8-c582980c0d38 . Cause: publisher is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying API Manager (AM) - Store cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/store.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying API Manager (AM) - Store service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] apistore [alias] 2a46279f-8ffa-4ab0-88df-28591053e9f6 . Cause: apistore is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) Manager cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/esb-cart-mgt.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) Manager service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] esbmgt [alias] 63e7e8c0-04f5-4486-af48-b171f1e52688 . Cause: esbmgt is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) Worker cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/esb-cart-worker.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) Worker service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] esbworker [alias] d940f54c-98fc-4c21-aafa-b31488b9616d . Cause: esbworker is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying Business Process Server (BPS) Manager cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/bps-cart-mgt.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying Business Process Server (BPS) Manager service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] bpsmgt [alias] 779291a8-a4f2-4ef7-9815-43675749a881 . Cause: bpsmgt is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying Business Process Server (BPS) Worker cartridge at /home/ubuntu/private-paas/resources/json/ec2/bps-cart-worker.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: ec2"}}Deploying Business Process Server (BPS) Worker service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] bpsworker [alias] 4aa5efa2-5b63-49aa-ada5-765bbf409a9d . Cause: bpsworker is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "agent.py", line 33, in getLBIp
    lb_ip=cluster['cluster'][0]['member'][0]['memberPublicIp']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It seems to be a permission issue. Have you provided correct EC2 identity and credentials? You can specify it in conf.sh file (found in the same directory as boot.sh) under EC2 section and run the boot.sh.

Comment: You mean, `export ec2_credentials=` is to be set to secret key?

Comment: Yes - set it to secret access key. And set other parameters like ec2_identity,ec2_availability_zone etc as well

Comment: Make sure you run clean.sh before running boot.sh again. It will clean previous installation.

Comment: No luck. I have run `clean.sh` prior to `boot.sh`. I have set the secret key in the EC2 section for `export ec2_credentials=`. I know the secret key is correct, because I have set it to `AWS_SECRET_KEY` and AWS EC2 CLI is working for me. (That means, the role assigned to me has sufficient access - as far as AWS EC2 is concerned.)

Comment: Are you sure that all the other information are also correct? A sample setting would looks like below. Please double check whether all the information are correct.


# EC2
export ec2_vpc="n"
export ec2_identity="SJKSJNNJNSJ12SKJNJKNS"
export ec2_credentials="snjansjan5n/sasknsjansjnSjnjs+"
export ec2_owner_id="329839289"
export ec2_keypair_name="raj-ec2"
export ec2_security_groups="all-open"
export ec2_availability_zone="ap-southeast-1b"
export ec2_security_group_ids=""
export ec2_subnet_id=""
export ec2_associate_public_ip_address="true"

Comment: The `ec2_credentials` is in the format of AWS_ACCESS_KEY/AWS_SECRET_KEY ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83525/discussion-between-cogitoergosum-and-depository).

Comment: Please have a look at the logs at $PPAAS_HOME/install/apache-stratos-default/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log which will have more clue. This issue normally happens if you give incorrect ec2 credentials.

Comment: Yes, please have a look at the wso2carbon.log or post it here by removing sensitive information. Without checking it, it is difficult to find the exact cause of this issue.

Comment: From logs: `Caused by: org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: request: POST https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1  [Action=DescribeRegions&Signature=h1aYBwv%2BVR0ixIu2LwmiSzRe5dtFvTnOocAeBSJ66y
8%3D&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-07-17T09%3A43%3A27.422Z&Version=2014-02-01&AWSAccessKeyId=i-eretweea]` and the note on time stamp used in signature - described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/set-up-ec2-cli-linux.html#set-up-ec2-cli-tools-on-amazon-linux) - may have a clue. Exploring now ....

Comment: could you please post the complete log here?

Comment: The logs are getting reported in UTC even though I have set the time zone for my instance as EDT (to match us-east-1d availability zone). I tried setting a JVM argument as `export EC2_JVM_ARGS=-Duser.timezone=America/New_York`. But, the logs are reported in UTC. As described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html), maybe this time zone setting is the reason.

I am trying to get the logs to my local computer with `scp` and `sftp`. I am getting a weird error like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17477226/919480). Exploring ...

Comment: So, I had entered the machine id for EC2 identity. I changed it to AWS_ACCESS_KEY and the HTTP 401 is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things during the WSO2 P.PaaS installation.

The user ID you use during installation should have full administration rights because it will be invoking certain AWS EC2 CLI commands. See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/set-up-ec2-cli-linux.html#verify_tool_setup_linux)

The `conf.sh` file in `private-paas` folder should look somewhat like this for IaaS section.

```
export iaas="ec2"
export region="ap-southeast-1"
export cartridge_base_img_id="ami-e6bd9eb4"
```

And, like this for the EC2 section.

```
export ec2_vpc="this-was-y-for-me"
export ec2_identity="AWS ACCESS KEY"  
export ec2_credentials="AWS SECRET KEY" 
export ec2_owner_id="num-owner-id" 
export ec2_keypair_name="as-applicable-to-you"
export ec2_security_groups="as-applicable-to-you"
export ec2_availability_zone="ap-southeast-1a"
export ec2_security_group_ids="as-applicable-to-you"
export ec2_subnet_id="as-applicable-to-you"
export ec2_associate_public_ip_address="as-applicable-to-you"
```

The ones listed above "as-applicable-to-you" can be obtained by running this on the command line `aws ec2 describe-instances`. See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/set-up-ec2-cli-linux.html#setting_up_ec2_command_linux) to know how to install and make use of AWS EC2 CLI.

The `ec2_availability_zone` is set to `ap-southeast-1a` because the base image is in Asia Pacific region. This is in sync with the `region` setting in the `IaaS` section. See [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-AMIs) for EC2 AMIs for P.PaaS.